# How to archieve pixel-perfect pixelart upscaling with css?

Tags: css, image, game-development, pixel-perfect

I want to upscale my pixelart sprite with css and have it look crisp.
But I have 3 issues with pixelart and css:

1. Upscaling is blurry by default (has been solved many times already)
2. CSS px is not the size of a screen's pixel (can't be solved apparently)
3. I can't find a way to upscale my img by an integer factor so pixels stay perfect squares (what I struggle to do)

[image: One of my failed attemps]

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to upscale your picture by an integer factor in order for the pixels to stay squares, and since CSS doesn't give you the "true size of 1 pixel" you have to run your own calculations, depending on the end user's viewport pixel width.

Here is an example:

```css
.pixel-perfect {
  image-rendering: crisp-edges; /*no blur*/

  /*pixel-perfect upscaling of a 15px wide image on a 1920px wide viewport by a factor of 4x */
  width: calc(calc(100vw / calc(1920 /*viewport screen pixel width, needs to be equivalent to 100vw for it to look best*/ / 4 /*factor*/)) * 15 /*pixelart width*/) 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <img class="pixel-perfect" src="https://imgur.com/3gtdA0P.png"/>
  </body>
</html>
```